# Using loop on one variable to keep value of a second variable into a third variable in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with both diagnosis codes (dx#) and a notation of whether that diagnosis was present prior to the recorded admission (dx#poa)

For instance `dx1=443`, and `dx1poa =="Y"` indicating that dx1 was present before the admission.

What I want to do is loop over each observation and if `dx#poa=="Y"` then I want to keep the value of `dx#` in another variable `com1` otherwise set `com#==""` or `com#==NA`

Below is a sample data frame with 4 observations that simulates the larger dataset I am working on.

```
pt<-c(1,2,3,4)
dx1<-c(443, 5521, 6647, 812)
dx2<-c(453, 5431, 779, 6782)
dx1poa <-c("Y","N","N","N")
dx2poa <-c("Y","N","Y","Y")
df<-data.frame(pt, dx1, dx2, dx1poa, dx2poa)
```

start with

```
> df
  pt  dx1  dx2 dx1poa dx2poa
1  1  443  453      Y      Y
2  2 5521 5431      N      N
3  3 6647  779      N      Y
4  4  812 6782      N      Y
```

and want

```
> df
  pt  dx1  dx2 dx1poa dx2poa  com1 com2
1  1  443  453      Y      Y   443  453
2  2 5521 5431      N      N    ""   ""
3  3 6647  779      N      Y    ""  779
4  4  812 6782      N      Y    "" 6782
```

Comment: Check out `ifelse`, as in `ifelse(df$dx1poa == 'Y', dx1, "")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
df<-data.frame(pt, dx1, dx2, dx1poa, dx2poa)
df
  pt  dx1  dx2 dx1poa dx2poa
1  1  443  453      Y      Y
2  2 5521 5431      N      N
3  3 6647  779      N      Y
4  4  812 6782      N      Y

df$com1 <- ifelse(df$dx1poa == 'Y', df$dx1, '')
df$com2 <- ifelse(df$dx2poa == 'Y', df$dx2, '')
df
  pt  dx1  dx2 dx1poa dx2poa com1 com2
1  1  443  453      Y      Y  443  453
2  2 5521 5431      N      N          
3  3 6647  779      N      Y       779
4  4  812 6782      N      Y      6782
```

Comment: Thanks! though I feel like a dunce for not thinking of this simple solution.